# How to Implement Amazon in-app purchase

Tags: android, kindle-fire, amazon-appstore

In my Android Application I want to implement Amazon In-App Purchase. But I don't know how to implement it?

Are there any Example code for me to look at?

https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/in-app-purchasing/sample-code/button-clicker.html

I use That code for In App, I follow the steps but I didnt get it.

Can any one tell me how to use it....

Comment: This will help you https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/earn/in-app-purchasing/docs-v2/implement-consumables-entitlements-and-subscriptions-in-iap-2.0

Answer (score 0):

check the following link...Whole process is described that how can you use Amazon in-app sdk for android:

https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/in-app-purchasing/reference/google-to-iap.html